# Rails SQL COUNT N+1 inefficiency

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a blog. On my index page, I pull in all blog posts. For each blog post, I count the number of comments on that post. This leads to an N+1 problem. My queries look as follows:

```
SELECT "blog_posts".* FROM "blog_posts" WHERE ("blog_posts"."published" = 't') ORDER BY published_at DESC
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" IN (1, 2, 3)) 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "blog_comments" WHERE ("blog_comments".blog_post_id = 10)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "blog_comments" WHERE ("blog_comments".blog_post_id = 9)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "blog_comments" WHERE ("blog_comments".blog_post_id = 8)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "blog_comments" WHERE ("blog_comments".blog_post_id = 2)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "blog_comments" WHERE ("blog_comments".blog_post_id = 7)
```

Is there a way in Rails to include the COUNT in the same way I include the users (SQL line 2)?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use counter cache: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter_cache

"With this declaration, Rails will keep the cache value up to date, and then return that value in response to the size method."

```
class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blog_comments
end

class BlogComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog_post, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Blog post would have a column named `blog_comments_count`.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you want a SQL query like:

```
  SELECT COUNT(*), blog_post_id
    FROM blog_comments
GROUP BY blog_post_id;
```

You can use this to create a hash from blog_post_id to the count of comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can also see something like this:

```
BlogComment.group('blog_post_id').count
```

In purely Rails Way. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dase](https://github.com/vovayartsev/dase) gem or one of techniques explained in [that video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJg3I-leoo4).

Example with Dase:

`Author.includes_count_of(:articles).each do |author|
  puts "#{author.name} has #{author.articles_count} articles"
end`

Answer (score 0):

This is an ActiveRecord query that searches my "site_access_log" table, consisting of web accesses to a site.

It selects the 'remote_addr' field from the first 15 records, along with the count for that IP, sorted in descending order by the count followed by ascending order for IP numbers that have the same count_number.

I'm using Postgres, which understands IPv4 numbers, so I cast the field to an `inet` type to allow correct sorting by value, rather than by ASCII value. If your database doesn't support inet values, you can always convert from IP to inet using Ruby's Socket or IPSocket library, then sort the retrieved results.

```
@remote_addr_results = SiteAccessLog.all(
  :select     => 'remote_addr, count(remote_addr) as remote_addr_count',
  :group      => :remote_addr,
  :order      => 'remote_addr_count desc, cast(remote_addr as inet)',
  :limit      => 15
)
puts @remote_addr_results.map{ |r| r.remote_addr_count << ' : ' << r.remote_addr }

>> 985 : 68.228.61.183
>> 572 : 205.203.134.197
>> 500 : 68.32.220.153
>> 460 : 72.200.64.128
>> 281 : 24.121.196.194
>> 262 : 99.91.9.155
>> 241 : 68.99.237.178
>> 213 : 68.99.119.137
>> 208 : 70.167.157.162
>> 204 : 201.165.6.2
>> 164 : 72.201.233.147
>> 155 : 75.245.177.106
>> 150 : 97.123.246.154
>> 149 : 201.165.190.98
>> 145 : 74.37.165.220
```

The generated SQL looks like:

```
SELECT remote_addr, count(remote_addr) as remote_addr_count                                                                       
FROM "site_access_logs"                                                                                                           
GROUP BY remote_addr                                                                                                              
ORDER BY remote_addr_count desc, cast(remote_addr as inet)                                                                        
LIMIT 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is step-by-step how to clean up nested N+1 and make this clean: [How to avoid N + 1 and keep your Ruby on Rails controller clean](https://jtway.co/how-to-avoid-n-1-and-keep-your-ruby-on-rails-controller-clean-b8589c8c6d39)